# Adding selected class to the closest tr

Tags: jquery

I have created a function for selecting all checkbox on checkbox with id selectall..

```
<tr class="">
    <td width="5%" class="center"><input type="checkbox" onclick="" value="0" id="selectall" name="chkRecordId"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="row_21" class="even">
     <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" id="CategoryCheckIn" value="21" class="case" name="data[Category][checkIn][]"></td>
</tr>

<tr id="row_1" class="odd">
    <td class="center"><input type="checkbox" id="CategoryCheckIn" value="1" class="case" name="data[Category][checkIn][]"></td>
 </tr>
```

Like this. Now I want to add code to select all checkbox with class .case along with that add class to the closest tr 'selected'

Function is going well in case of checkbox select. But I am confused in adding class to tr.
Though I have tried my code here is written down. It fails in case of addClass if select all is clicked.

```
$(function(){
$("#selectall").click(function () {
    $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
});

$(".case").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");
    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});

$(".case:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
});

});
```

I have submit button with id 'submit' I wanna check on submit click if any of checkbox.case is checked else return false.

Comment: You should take a look at [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) if you are using jQuery 1.6+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest the following:

```
$('#selectall').change(function () {
    var thisClosest = $(this).closest('tr'),
        checked = this.checked;
    // selecting the elements by class:
    $('.case')
    // setting the property (not the attribute) to be equal that of #selectall
    .prop('checked', checked)
    // finding the closest tr element of each of those check-boxes
    .closest('tr')
    // adding the closest tr of the #selectall element (cached earlier)
    // then calls the addClass() or removeClass() methods depending on
    // the #selectall being checked (addClass()) or unchecked (removeClass())
    .add(thisClosest)[checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
});

$('.case').change(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr')[this.checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/brhMv/2/).

The above updated to the following:

```
$('#selectall').change(function () {
    var thisClosest = $(this).closest('tr'),
        checked = this.checked;
    $('.case').prop('checked', checked).closest('tr').add(thisClosest)[checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
});

$('.case').change(function () {
    var that = this,
        $that = $(that),
        checked = that.checked,
        $selectall = $('#selectall');
    $that.closest('tr').add($selectall.closest('tr'))[checked ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass']('selected');
    $selectall.prop('checked', false);
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/brhMv/3/).

Further to your original question, as to how to check for any `.case` elements being checked on submit:

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if (!$('.case:checked').length) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

References:

- [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`:checked` selector](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`submit()`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/).

Comment: It doesn't remove class if seperate checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: I hadn't realised that you needed that aspect as well, my apologies. Answer updated/edited to include.

Comment: @sankalp: now edited to removed the `#selectall`'s check if an element is unchecked (which seems like the/a desired response).

Comment: Are you familiar with CakePhp. Actually I am confused to put this form return function on that. I know the way but how it would be implemented in that if I am using `$this->Js->submit` ? have you any idea to continue on that.

Comment: I vote `+10` for writing minimize code. I always wish to do that. :)

Comment: I have written code for returning false with a function on form submit. But can't integrate it with the Js Helper.

Comment: I'm afraid I've no experience at all with CakePHP, so I'm unable to help with that aspect (though if I were I'd argue it warranted a separate question).

Comment: No issue. I have opened next question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167424/how-to-add-2-callback-to-the-jshelper-in-cakephp-2-x

Answer (score 0):

Though my code is bit long but I have found perfect solution for it.

```
$("#selectall").click(function () {
    $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    if($('.case').prop('checked'))
        $('.case').closest("tr").addClass("selected");
    else
        $('.case').closest("tr").removeClass("selected");
});

$(".case").click(function(){
    $(this).closest("tr").toggleClass("selected");
    if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
        $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
    } else {
        $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
    }
});

$(".case:checked").each(function() {
    $(this).closest("tr").addClass("selected");
});
```

It works well but still I am confused to verify on submit if single checkbox is checked or not ?